# Email issues with smtp

Tags: email

Are email addresses case sensitive ? When trying to automatic mails via job  in UNIX server the emails are not delivered to destination. Instead throwing error message 554 transaction failed

Comment: hostnames aren't, usernames MAY be, depending on the receiving and/or sending system. And in any case, offtopic, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases, in UNIX systems, things are case sensitive.  In cases where it's not, it's always better to assume that it is.  It's a bad practice that Windows ever let us run around with things NOT being case sensitive.